# Fastest way to add two arrays to create a matrix with python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I have two numpy arrrays:

```
import numpy as np
points_1 = np.array([1.5,2.5,1,3])
points_2 = np.array([3,4])
```

I would like to take evey point from points_1 array and deduce whole points_2 array from it in order to get a matrix
I would like to get

```
[[-1.5,-2.5]
 [-0.5,-1.5]
 [-2 , -3]
 [0 , -1]]
```

I know there is a way with iteration

```
points = [x - points_2 for x  in points_1] 
points = np.array(points)
```

However this option is not fast enough. In reality I am using much bigger arrays.
Is there some fastser way?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You just have to chose `points_2` "better" (better means here an other dimension of you matrix), then it works as you expect it:

so do not use `points_2 = np.array([3, 4])` but `points_2 = np.array([[3],[4]])`:

```
import numpy as np
points_1 = np.array([1.5,2.5,1,3])
points_2 = np.array([[3],[4]])
points = (points_1 - points_2).transpose()

print(points)
```

results in:

```
[[-1.5 -2.5]
 [-0.5 -1.5]
 [-2.  -3. ]
 [ 0.  -1. ]]
```

Comment: Is there a fast way of converting `np.array([3, 4])` into `np.array([[3],[4]])`

Comment: You can do: `points_2 = np.array([3, 4])` and then `points = (points_1 - points_2[:, np.newaxis]).transpose()`. Should I update my answer?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't the whole array at once. You can use generators and benefit from lazy evaluation:

```
import numpy as np
points_1 = np.array([1.5,2.5,1,3])
points_2 = np.array([3,4])

def get_points():
    def get_points_internal():
        for p1 in points_1:
            for p2 in points_2:
                yield [p1 - p2]

    x = len(points_1) * len(points_2)
    points_1d = get_points_internal()
    for i in range(0, int(x/2)):
        yield [next(points_1d), next(points_1d)]

points = get_points()
```

Answer (score 0):

Make use of numpy's [broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html) feature. This will provide the following:

```
import numpy as np
points_1 = np.array([1.5,2.5,1,3])
points_2 = np.array([3,4])

points = points_1[:, None] - points_2
print(points)
```

Output:

```
 [[-1.5 -2.5]
 [-0.5 -1.5]
 [-2.  -3. ]
 [ 0.  -1. ]]
```

It works by repeating the operation over the 1 dimension injected by the None index. For more info see the link.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in one line :

```
np.subtract.outer(points_1,points_2)
```

This is vectored so very fast.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use tranposed matrix.

```
points_1-np.transpose([points_2])
```

and for your result

```
np.tanspose(points_1-np.transpose([points_2]))
```